# How to prevent unwanted re-renders to stop another API call in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a **parent** component (`Cart`) and a **child** component (`CartItem`).

in the **parent**, there is a `button` that counts on the state that changes by the `checkAvailability` function which passed to the child via props,

```
import {useState} from "react";
import CartItem from "./CartItem";

const Cart = ({cart}) => {
    const [available, setAvailable] = useState(true);

    const checkAvailability = (check) => {
        setAvailable(check)
    }


    return (
        <>
          {cart.items.map((item) => (
              item.is_valid && 

                  <CartItem 
                      key={item.id}
                      checkAvailability={checkAvailability}
                  />
          ))}


          <button disabled={available} >Click Me!</button>
        </>
    )
}

export default Cart;
```

in the **child** component, an **API call** returns `true or false` called by `useEffect`.

```
import {useState, useEffect} from "react";


const CartItem = ({checkAvailability}) => {
const [newData, setNewData] = useState(null);


    const handleCheck = async () => {
    
       const data = await api.call();
        setNewData(data)
       
       if(newData.available === false) {
        checkAvailability(false)
       } else if(newData.available === true) {
        checkAvailability(true)
       }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        handleCheck();
    }, []);



    
    return (
        <div> Item </div>
    )
};

export default CartItem;
```

**issue:**

every time the components mount, the API call in the child returns a value, that value gets passed to the parent by the `checkAvailability` function as a prop, which changes the state in the parent, when the state changes a **re-render happen** which restarts the circle infinitely.

- the main thing is the button gets disabled when the API call returns a {false} value. if this way won't do the job, is there another way of doing it?.

what is the solution?.

Comment: I think the issue here is that you aren't specifying any React keys for the cart items you are mapping. Try adding a key that is intrinsic to each cart item, like `item.id` for example.

Comment: @DrewReese In the original code, they are present. I decided not to write them for the simplification of the code.

Comment: Can you please update your question to include all relevant code? It should be a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) enough for use to sufficiently and (possibly easily) reproduce on our own. Is the `Cart` component remounting for some reason? I see no reason why the `CartItem` components would remount.

Comment: Did you try adding checkAvilability as dependency of useEffect?

Comment: You should have the api call in the parent component. Why is it a child component?

Comment: Looks like all of your cart items share just one availability bool stored in the parent, which probably isn't what you want. E.g. 5 cart items all sharing one "true" availability state doesn't make much sense. As the availability state is per cart item, it should probably be stored in the child item.

Comment: @DrewReese believe me brother all the rest of the code is irrelevant.

Comment: @Prebiusta I have, didn't work.

Comment: @Samathingamajig didn't write it but the API call needs some information from the child component.

Comment: Not that I don't believe you, but I don't see anything in your provided snippet that would cause the `CartItem` components to remount and run the `useEffect` repeatedly, so I'm using an educated hunch that `Cart` component is being remounted, thus remounting its entire subtree. *Something* outside the code you've provided is relevant.

Comment: @LukeBriggs the main thing that I want, is the button gets disabled when the API call returns a {false} value.

Comment: In that case the safer React way would be to write a single function which collects all the availabilities in one go, and then determines if any were false using something like `Promise.all(cart.items.map(item => getAvailability(item)).includes(false)` at the <Cart> level. This makes your rendering deterministic, which would also make cart item removal a lot simpler as well because there's more structure to your state. This is also easier to optimise as one web request.

Comment: @LukeBriggs it would be very nice if you put it as an answer and where to put it because I'm not familiar with promises very well. thank you.

Comment: @DrewReese excuse me I forgot to add the state in the child component, but would that make a difference?.

Comment: It could, `newData.available === false` will be comparing the value of `newData` from the current render cycle, not what it will be updated to for the next render cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you resolved the current issue of infinite re-renders, you'll still have multiple API requests if there are multiple `<CartItem/>` components.

A better approach will be to move the API call to the parent. This will ensure it's called once regardless of the number of cart items it has. If the cart items need to know the value of `available`, then pass it to them.

```
const CartItem = ({ available }) => {
  return <div> Item </div>
}
```

Comment: Let us say for each item in the cart, I want to check if it's available in storage, if not the API will return a false value, so in this case, multiple API requests are needed.

Comment: Since the `<Cart />` renders the `<CartItem/>`s, it already knows what the cart items should be. You could send an array of the item ids in that one request to the backend and have it return an array of booleans indicating which items are available in the storage...